# linked list segfault after first traversal

Tags: c, linked-list

I am using the linked list example [from junghans](http://home.fhtw-berlin.de/~junghans/cref/EXAMPLES/linklst1.c) and try to make it work
with some server code. In the char array, I could insert a host (from inet_ntoa)
and update it's age. So I can send one packet to the daemon, but then it crashes.
I tried setting  `next_pointer=start_pointer;` because from what I read, it will be
a circular list. However, after receiving the second packet, strcpy crashes..

**Questions:**

1. How do I point to the beginning, if next_pointer=start_pointer doesn't do the trick?
2. Do I need to free, before overwrite a member of the char array?

```
struct x {
    char name[20];
    int age;
    struct x *next_rec;
};

struct x *start_pointer;
struct x *next_pointer;    // starting hosts, will be overwritten 
char *names[] = {
    "127.0.0.1",
    "evil666",
     "192.168.56.101",
     ""
};
int ages[] = {0,20,30,0};
// some other code
while (1) {
    sleep(1);
    us=time(NULL);
    printf("%ld, Sleep a second\n", us);
    buf[0] = 0x0;
    current_host = 0x0;
    memset (buf,0,sizeof buf);

    if(recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&si_other, &slen)==-1)
        diep("recvfrom()");

    current_host = inet_ntoa(si_other.sin_addr);
    if(!current_host)
        diep("inet_ntoa()");

    /* linked list initialization */

    /* Initalise 'start_pointer' by reserving
     * memory and pointing to it
     */
    start_pointer=(struct x *) malloc (sizeof (struct x));
    if(!start_pointer)
        diep("start pointer on holiday");

    /* Initalise 'next_pointer' to point
     * to the same location.
     */

    next_pointer=start_pointer;

    /* Put some data into the reserved
     * memory.
     */

    strcpy(next_pointer->name,current_host);
    next_pointer->age = ages[count];

    /* Loop until all data has been read    */

    while ( ages[++count] != 0 )
    {
        /* Reserve more memory and point to it  */
        next_pointer->next_rec=(struct x *) malloc (sizeof (struct x));
        if(!next_pointer)
            diep("next pointer on holiday");

        strcpy(next_pointer->name, names[count]);
        next_pointer->age = ages[count];
    }
    next_pointer->next_rec=NULL;
    next_pointer=start_pointer;

    /* insert new record, update age  */
    while (next_pointer != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s   ", next_pointer->name);
        if(strstr(next_pointer->name,current_host)) {
            printf("%d \n", next_pointer->age+1);
        }
        if(!strstr(next_pointer->name,current_host)) {
            printf("%d \n", next_pointer->age);
        }
        next_pointer=next_pointer->next_rec;
    }
    next_pointer=start_pointer; // XXX
```

Comment: Oh the indentation makes it look so much easier on the eye. :) are you sure count is within the array boundary?

Comment: What is count? where is it initialised ?

Comment: You seemed to have snipped it. It is in the Junghans code (which is informative, but terrible, IMHO) BTW: what is the use of the ages[] array? It does not seem to make any sense to me...

Comment: You also forget to define and initialise slen. Please post complete, compilable code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you missed this part from the linked C file in the init loop: `next_pointer=next_pointer->next_rec`. As a result, in first iteration you allocate new list node, but then modify contents of the first node. And then in subsequent iterations you allocate even more nodes, but you still only modify the first node.

Then right after the loop you terminate the list, but since you did not update next_pointer in the meantime, you're list has now a single node. (And you leaked some memory there, overwriting addresses with next allocations and NULL, so now you cannot free it.)

As to your more specific questions:

Question 1: next_pointer is only a helper variable to iterate over a list. If you want a circular list, you should set some next_rec pointer to start_pointer. You could do it like this:

```
for (next_pointer = start_pointer;
     next_pointer->next_rec != NULL; /* This is not the last node. */
     next_pointer = next_pointer->next_rec /* Move to the next node. */)
  ;
/* At this moment next_pointer points to the last node of the list. */
next_pointer->next_rec = start_pointer; /* And a cycle is there. */
```

However, you can actually do this while initialising your loop. When you exit from the init loop, next_pointer is indeed pointing at the last node. So instead of doing `next_pointer->next_rec=NULL` to terminate the list, do `next_pointer->next_rec = start_pointer` to make a cycle.

**UPDATE** That is, if you do want a circular list. Because in fact `next_pointer=start_pointer` will make next_pointer point at the beginning. So I assumed you want the end of the list point to the beginning (as you mentioned circular list).

Question 2: If you didn't allocate a string, explicitly (with malloc) or implicitly (for example with strdup), you don't need to free it. In particular in that code there are no strings to free:

- next_pointer->name is an array within structure. You allocated it along with the structure (list node), and it will be freed with the node.
- names is an array of pointers to the constant strings. They were not allocated, but instead will be part of data section of application compiled code, and thus cannot be freed.

Last but not least: lookout for `strcpy`. If you are copying only IPs there, 20 characters will always be enough, but the first moment you'll try to copy something larger, you have buffer overflow and can overwrite some other data. You should be using `strncpy`, with n = 19, followed by `next_pointer->name[19] = 0` to ensure null termination.

And you don't need to run `strstr()` twice there. It either returns NULL pointer or not, so you could run

```
if (strstr( /* .. the arguments .. */ )) {
  /* ... */
} else {
  /* what if the call did return NULL. */
}
```